# Notificacion en android setlargeicon

Tags: android, push-notification, android-imageview

buenas.
estoy tratando de implementar en una notificacion el metodo setLargeIcon este me pide un Bitmap en mi caso solo me da la opción  de Bitmapcompat e visto unos ejemplos como se hace normalmente con Bitma pero este  ami me genera un error

```
 picture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new   URL(NotificationsConstants.URL_IMAGE).getContent());
```

en el notificationcompat

```
.setLargeIcon(picture)
```

esto me genera error alguna solución a como implementar *BitmapCompat*

Comment: podrias incluir el log para ver que error da?

Comment: me aparece como si *BitmapFactory* no se pudiera usar la única opción que me da es *Bitmapcompat* algún ejemplo con el segundo mencionado seria muy util gracias...